# Indenting multiple lines: Keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse

I think I was told once how to indent an entire collection of lines quickly and at the same time with a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse (I'm using Juno with PyDev-Python). Does anyone know of such a shortcut? I can't seem to dig anything up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select all, then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

The advantage of this method over selecting some lines, then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, is that it is much faster to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, than tabbing lines at a time. I do automatic indenting all the time, it's basically in my reflex. Like saving.

[A quick googling](http://www.rossenstoyanchev.org/write/prog/eclipse/eclipse3.html) would have helped you faster.

Comment: That deleted the lines.

Comment: What? Are your shortcuts remapped? Just go in `Preferences`, the search for `Keyboard Shortcuts`. Add `CTRL+I` shortcut to `Correct Indentation`.

Comment: @Matt, you must've pressed Ctrl + D.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Nope, triple checked...hitting `I`

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a Java source file?

Comment: PyDev, I didn't think it would matter. After looking through the preferences I've realized it does. Edited the OP with relevant info.

Comment: Ah, there's your problem right there. Go to prefs->keys->correct indentation. It should apply to the PyDev perspective aswell.

Comment: Also, Right Click on PyDev Perspective (upper right corner) -> `Customize` -> `Command Groups Availability` -> Check `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 11):

Just highlight the lines and push tab.

Comment: How the **** did I not think of that. :(

Answer (score 11):

Select the lines and Press TAB - for Right

Select the lines and Press SHIFT+TAB - for Left